# How can i force the execution of a subsequent case in Swift?

Tags: swift

According to Switch statement in Swift, what does mean "fall through"?

Does "fall through" forces the execution ...?

Example:

```
let integerToDescribe = 5
var description = "The number \(integerToDescribe) is"
switch integerToDescribe {
case 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19:
    description += " a prime number, and also"
    fallthrough
default:
    description += " an integer."
}
print(description)
```

Comment: Why don't you test this and see what happens?

Comment: That code example in the Swift book is followed by an exact description of the code path with explanations.

Comment: "Does "fall through" forces the execution ...?"
I know. I'm asking to make sure that i'm right. Maybe i see what is happening ... but i can't get it? By - the - way nobody answered yes/no. Only global description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does exactly what it says — the `fallthrough` keyword "falls through" to the next case in your switch expression.

Executing your example as a playground:

[image: Fallthrough]

If you commented out `fallthrough`, the `default` case wouldn't be reached.

Comment: Thanks. But you didn't answered to the questions. I can't get it. So i'm asking!

Comment: Yes, it "forces execution" in the sense that the subsequent case will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Swift `switch` statements break on each case, unlike C or Objective-C switch statements.  `fallthrough` allows the value being tested to "fall through" to the next `case`.  So in your switch, the value 5 will will append " a prime number, and also" and " an integer." to `description`, because it it's caught by `case 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19:`, and the `default` case.

Comment: Thanks. But you didn't answered to the question #2. I can't get it. So i'm asking!

Comment: @АлександрЖелезняк `fallthrough` forces the switch to move to the next `case`.